# R subsetting data.frame with conditions from other data.frames

Tags: r, subset

I have three R data with the following formats,

Data1

```
ID   V2  V2.1  V2.2 V2.3 ...V2.101

0    54   40   50   55       43
1    20   35   14   40       13
2    10   33   8    44       8

.    .    .    .    .        .
.    .    .    .    .        .
99   8    38   10   50      10
```

Data2

```
ID   V2   V2.1   V2.2  V2.3 ...V2.101

0    1.5   1.5   1.4    1.3      1.5
1    1.3   3     3     1.5       3
2    1.5   4     4     1.8       5

.     .     .    .     .        .
.     .     .    .     .        .
99   1.4    12   8    1.9       8
```

Data3

```
ID   V2    V2.1   V2.2  V2.3 ...V2.101

0    1.4   1.3   1.3    1.2      1.2
1    1.4   3.1   3.2     1.4       4
2    1.3   4     4.2     1.3       3

.     .     .    .     .        .
.     .     .    .     .        .
99   1.2    10   7.5    1.6       9
```

---

V2 to V101 in data1 represents same observation(Angle) made 100 times for each ID values in data1 and V2 to V101 in data2 and data3 represent bond for similar observations. I want to extract ID and variable(angle) value from data1, if variable (angle) value is less than 30 also corresponding values is less than 1.5 either in data2 or data3.  Basically I want extract data with angle is less than 30 and also either one of the bond is less than 1.5.

The desired output should have ID and variable index, Angle(from data1) and Bond( smallest bond from data2 and data3 should be reported)

```
ID   Variable   Angle   Bond

10     V2.5     29      1.5
40     V2.36    13      1.3
50     V2.99     8      1.4
..       ..     ..      1.0
```

I have tried with subset command,

```
my.data<-subset(data1, V2<30)
```

But I dont know how to include all V2 value(V2 TO V2.101) and also putting conditions from data2 and data3.

Comment: Can you post expected output for some sample data frames?

Comment: You have multiple conditions to be satisfied per row. For example, row1, V2 may satisfy your conditions, but V2.1 may not. How do you deal with such situations? Output will be useful here.

Comment: please also use `dput` so users do not have to go through lengths to create examples that match your input/output

Comment: Put your data in the long format and merge.

Comment: I find this link very help when [converting from wide to long](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
d1 <- melt(df1, id.var='ID', value.name = "angle")
d2 <- melt(df2, id.var='ID', value.name = "bond")
d3 <- melt(df3, id.var='ID', value.name = "bond2")

dall <- join_all(list(d1,d2,d3), by= c('ID', 'variable'))
dall2 <- melt(dall, id.var = c('ID', 'variable', 'angle'), value.name = "bond") 
subset(dall2, angle < 30 & bond < 1.5)

   ID variable angle variable.1 bond
2   1       V2    20       bond  1.3
17  1       V2    20      bond2  1.4
18  2       V2    10      bond2  1.3
```